# how to call function in controller from hook in PrestaShop

Tags: prestashop

I have hook the same below

```
public function hookActionProductAdd($params){
// how to call function from Admincontroller
}
```

i want to get parameter from $params, and i have controller, i want call Processproduct function in hookActionProductAdd when product added.

```
class GetProductController extends ModuleAdminController{
public function Processproduct(){
    self::$slimit = ( int ) Configuration::get ( 'PS_COMMIT_ITEM' );
    //do something
    }
```

}
but i don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can get any controller by the static function :

```
AdminController::getController($class_name)
```

Same with "Controller" and "ModuleFrontController" classes

Comment: i want to call function with name "example", but AdminController::getController($solrCall) i wanna call function of this class.

Comment: I just don't understand what you want here, but i think it's more likely a POO problem than a prestashop one.

Comment: I find that, $class_name called AdminController::getController($class_name), must be declare in class_index file in cache folder, but my custom controller not appear in there, cause i cannot use  AdminController::getController(), it get error cannot find class...... Sorry for my english!

Comment: Ok i finally got it. Customs modules aren't defined in the autoload. You need to include this file yourself before to call it with this function. You can add theses lines in your module contructor : 

$autoload = Autoload::getInstance();
$autoload->index["AdminmycustomController"] = dirname(__FILE__).'/folderofmycontroller/AdminmycustomController.php'; 

And then you can call your controller from anywhere in your module with that :

$thecontroller = AdminControllerCore::getController("AdminmycustomController");

Comment: Thank Lliw very much!

Comment: No problem. You should close that topic ;)